# How do I serialize this kind of json?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON string (not created by me) that has identifiers not valid in C#, like this:

```
"OBSBasic.SelectScene": [],
"libobs.hide_scene_item.Captura de Janela": [],
```

and

```
 "push-to-mute-delay": 0,
```

and son on...

[here's](http://pastebin.com/5peAqeuV) the full json.

My question is:

How can I convert that JSON into a kind of Dictionary so that I can like that:

```
dic["sources"][0]["settings"]["window"] = "XXXX";
```

I don't know for sure all the possible properties names that JSON file can have, so I'd like to really convert it into an array-baseed approach so that I can access it from a *key* rather a property name from my object used to deserialized that would eventually fail if a new property was generated, for example.

I tried without success something like this:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr);
data.sources.settings.window = "xxxx";
```

That resulted in a runtime exception:

> Exception thrown:
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in
>   Microsoft.CSharp.dll Exception thrown:
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in
>   System.Core.dll

I have no code else to show bcause I'm stuck at how the dictionary would look like to be passed in `DeserializeObject<T>()` method. I'd like to serialized that JSON object back to string later.

Comment: `dic["sources"]["settings"]["window"] = "XXXX";` - sources is an array, not a dictionary. You'd need something like `dic["sources"][0]["settings"]["window"] = "XXXX";` AFAIK.

Comment: @codran that's right, I'll edit the code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse your JSON into a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) you can use the syntax you want to access your data:

```
    JToken dic = JToken.Parse(json);

    Console.WriteLine(dic["sources"][1]["settings"]["window"]);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jZrI44